# Getting country code for QLocale::Country

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to find the country code for a given [QLocale::Country](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#Country-enum) value. In the manual I have found only this function, that does something similar: [QLocale::name](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#name).

> QString QLocale::name () const
>
> Returns the language and country of this locale as a string of the
>   form "language_country", where language is a lowercase, two-letter ISO
>   639 language code, and country is an uppercase, two- or three-letter
>   ISO 3166 country code.

The second part of the return value is exactly what I need, so I have constructed the following function:

```
QString getCountryCode(QLocale::Country c)
{
    return QLocale(QLocale::AnyLanguage, c).name().split('_').at(1).toLower();
}
```

Strangely enough, if I call this function the following way:

```
qDebug() << getCountryCode(QLocale::Canada);
```

It will produce this output:

```
"us"
```

I have expected "ca"!
On the other hand, if I call it like:

```
qDebug() << getCountryCode(QLocale::Hungary);
```

then it will produce the correct answer:

```
"hu"
```

What am I missing here? (I am using Qt 5.2)

Comment: This is because locale for Canada is en_us.

Comment: The second part should be the ISO 3166 country code. In case of Canada it is "ca". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2. Or is this function really just about the language? If so, how do I get the country code?

Comment: By the way, it makes sense, because I tend to get incorrect results with English speaking countries. Although I would expect to get a different result for the United Kingdom, for which I still get "us" instead of "gb". In the case of Germany "de", and Austria "at" I get correct results.

Comment: a country code for QLocale::Canada?

Comment: In general. I would like to have a function, that returns the corresponding country code to any QLocale::Country value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, given the feature you want isn't directly available, please [submit a feature request](http://bugreports.qt-project.org/) on the bugtracker.

Apart from that, **you can't build a QLocale object with `AnyLanguage`**. That makes absolutely no sense -- a QLocale object fully identifies a *specific* locale. Which one should it pick for Canada, `fr_CA` or `en_CA`?

Solution: use

```
QList<QLocale> locales = QLocale::matchingLocales(QLocale::AnyLanguage,
                                                  QLocale::AnyScript,
                                                  QLocale::Canada);
```

then take the first of the list (if exists) and extract the country name as you were doing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really useful. If the function is really unavailable, this may be the closest we can get. Although there is still a problem: in the case of 29 countries, there are no matching locales. So my last question is: if I want this to work for really any countries, what options do I have except for a huge switch?